# can we block system notifications from a wpf app in windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am working on a WPF application my requirement is like when my application is running i want to block all the notification from other applications.So i need to block all notifications from my app.is that possible?

I found that we can block notifications through the windows settings.

http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/10/12/stop-notifications-windows-8-1/

I want to implement the same thing via code from my application?

Comment: Are you sure this is an ethical idea? I do understand that sometimes there is a good business reason, but just hearing it, it does sound awfully shady.

Comment: You say two contradictory things *"i want to block all the notification from other applications."* and *"So i need to block all notifications from my app."* So which is it you are trying to do, stop your app from sending notifications or disabling notifications from other applications you did not write from inside your app?

Comment: @ Scott. Sorry for the misunderstanding, my requirement is when my application is running,no notifications should appear.

Comment: @ Alan I know its not a good practice to block system notifications, but requirements demands that.

Comment: I could imagine a simple use case: an app to let me focus better by avoiding other apps showing any notifications for a certain time (e.g. during a 25min Pomodoro-focus-sprint).